# array_filter for making breadcrumb

Tags: php, breadcrumbs, array-filter

I wrote a simple function (copied and adapted, more like it!) to make breadcrumb for one application. My folder structure is such that if some folders are ignored, the trail would still work. I have looked it for far too long with no progress ...

```
function breadCrumb(){

// folders to ignore 
    $filterFolders = array('360', 'files');

if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1)){
    $dirlist = explode('/', $location);
    }else{
    $dirlist = array();

    }
/** update the array with non required folders **/ 
$filteredArr = array_diff_key($dirlist, array_flip($filterFolders));

$count = array_push($filteredArr, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    echo '<a href="'.$address.'">Home</a>';

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    echo '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<a href="'.($address .= '/'.$filteredArr[$i]).'">'.ucfirst($filteredArr[$i]).'</a>';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: It doesn't seem to ignore the folders, and spits out the array as they were (taken from $_server variable). I think I am doing it right, I would have thought it would go through the loop, remove the key where values matches the $filterFolders.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the assignment operator (`=`) instead of equality-comparision (`==`) in your if-condition?

Comment: @ccKep, that shouldn't affect the filtering though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any use of **array_filter** in your code, contrary to what's suggested by the question title. However, You should be running the difference function on *values*, not on *keys* (because you didn't specify any) in this case.

Hence

```
$filteredArr = array_diff_key($dirlist, array_flip($filterFolders));
                          ^
```

Should be

```
$filteredArr = array_diff($dirlist,$filterFolders); // you don't even ve to flip
```

For example

```
$filterFolders = array('360', 'files');
```

What would you expect those keys to be? they are `0` for the value `360` and `1` for the value `'files'`, so checking the difference of keys won't do what's expected.

Comment: Yes, however I am using array_flip to match the values of each key. I thought that would work?

Comment: Remove the flip as well. If you are flipping $filterFolders then you have to flip $dirlist as well, and there is no need to flip anything at all.

Comment: yes @Hanky, I will go back to it, I understand what you are saying, however, I have undefined offset issue now - but I think I know where I stuffed up. Thank you, I will post the update. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok lets see the updated code and the issue with it :)

Comment: ok, so I have got it to work. I changed the code a bit, I think this might be better (however, I may have to go a entirely different way for my breadcrumb solution, but to close this topic, this is what I have got):
   `code`
    foreach($dirlist as $k=>$v)
    {
    if(!in_array($v, $filterFolders)){
    echo $separator.'<a href='.$dblQuote.DIR_BASE.$v.$dblQuote.'>'.ucfirst($v).'</a>';
    }
    }

(I used some variables to store double quote and root folder). 

Thank you Hanky 웃 Panky for your help! Cheers

Comment: Great that you got it to work, if my answer didn't help reach that solution please don't feel obliged and you can un-accept it regardless of the effort made.